# launching 2 popup windows in html/javascript from php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html, social-networking

in my code I can get one window to appear or the other, but cannot get both to launch at the same time.
If both checkmarks are checked, it will default to the first only. If second is only check, it will go to the second if/popup url location.
How do I launch two popup windows with 2 different urls?

```
<form action="" method="POST" target="popup">
        Send a message  : <input type="text" name="twitmessage"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="twitter" value="My Posting Text">Would you like to send to Twitter?<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="facebook" value="Stuff to Post to facebook">Would you like to post to Facebook?<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_cycle" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['twitmessage'] = $_POST['twitmessage'];

if(isset($_POST['submit_cycle'])) {
        if($_POST['twitter']){
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.open('../index.php?p=members','popup','width=700,height=400,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1') ;</script>";
                //header("location: ../index.php?p=members");
        }
        if($_POST['facebook']){
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.open('../index.php?p=paybill','popup','width=700,height=400,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1') ;</script>";
                //header("location: ../index.php?p=paybill");
        }else{
                echo "Something bad happened";
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your windows the same name ('popup' in your case):

```
window.open(url1, 'popup', options);
window.open(url2, 'popup', options);
```

browser will reuse first window for the second popup.

Give your windows different name, e.g. 'popup1' and 'popup2':

```
window.open(url1, 'popup1', options);
window.open(url2, 'popup2', options);
```

That will cause 2 different popups to open.

Comment: Or you can just put a timestamp there to make it different every time.